# Why is my CSS stylesheet not working/linking to my HTML file anymore?

Tags: html, css

I have already searched for an answer on a lot of forums and I looked at maybe 50 google links but haven't found nothing working yet...

My CSS don't show up on my HTML.

My code was working just fine until I added a flexbox container and 2 flexbox in it.

I always test my codes so I know the flexbox is working outside of this particular HTML file.

Also, I noticed that my CSS wasn't updated on "inspect element" on my localhost/#my_file#.
This has happened already in the past and I solved the issue by changing my file location and changing it again to the old location. (idk how rhat worked).

Anyway, if I copied and paste my CSS updated sheet on the "inspect element" page, I can se my flexbox just fine.

So I doubted that was because of an error in my CSS but I'm never too sure so I even checked it on : https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input

And there was only 1 error but I checked for it in my whole CSS file and 1) I can't find it 2) I deleted everything that looked the most like the error and that still doesn't work.

And obviously, I think it's not error related because it was working just fine in the "inspect element" thing.

Also I know that I do attention mistakes, dumb mistakes so... you know.

I'm currently learning so please if you see any errors in my code, tell me !

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Darki0ni-s-website</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="styles/portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src=
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
        function validateForm()                                    
{ 
    var name = document.forms["myForm"]["name"];               
    var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"];    
    var message = document.forms["myForm"]["message"];   
   
    if (name.value == "")                                  
    { 
        document.getElementById('errorname').innerHTML="Please enter a valid name";  
        name.focus(); 
        return false; 
    }else{
        document.getElementById('errorname').innerHTML="";  
    }
       
    if (email.value == "")                                   
    { 
        document.getElementById('erroremail').innerHTML="Please enter a valid email address"; 
        email.focus(); 
        return false; 
    }else{
        document.getElementById('erroremail').innerHTML="";  
    }
   
    if (email.value.indexOf("@", 0) < 0)                 
    { 
        document.getElementById('erroremail').innerHTML="Please enter a valid email address"; 
        email.focus(); 
        return false; 
    } 
   
    if (email.value.indexOf(".", 0) < 0)                 
    { 
        document.getElementById('erroremail').innerHTML="Please enter a valid email address"; 
        email.focus(); 
        return false; 
    } 
   
    if (message.value == "")                           
    {
        document.getElementById('errormsg').innerHTML="Please enter a valid message"; 
        message.focus(); 
        return false; 
    }else{
        document.getElementById('errormsg').innerHTML="";  
    }
   
    return true; 
}
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
  
            $("a").on('click', function (event) {
  

                if (this.hash !== "") {
  
                    event.preventDefault();
  
                    var hash = this.hash;
  
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
                    }, 500, function () {

                        window.location.hash = hash;
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
        <header class="header">
            <article id="accueil"></article>
            <div id="header">
                <div id="background">
                    <article style="margin-bottom: 175px;" ><br></article>
                    <h1>MY NAME</h1>
                    <h4>___________________</h4>
                    <h2>Développeuse web débutante</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>
              <a href="#a-propos">À Propos</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#competences">Compétences</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#accueil" class="actif">&#69716;</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
          <p id="a-propos"></p>
    <h3>À Propos de moi</h3>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="flexbox-left">
            <p>Qui suis-je ?</p>
            <p>blablabla </p>
        </div>
        <div class="flexbox-right">
            <p>blablabla <br>
                blabla <br> 
            </p>    
        </div>
    </div>
         <p id="competences"></p>
        <h3>Compétences</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra. Lectus magna fringilla urna.</p>
        <p id="contact"></p>
        <h3>Contact</h3>
        <div class="container">
        <form name="myForm" action="mail.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
            <table class="form-style">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <label for ="name">
                        Your name <span class="required">*</span>
                     </label>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <input type="text" name="name" class="long" id="name"/>
                     <span class="error" id="errorname"></span>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <label for ="email">
                       Your email address <span class="required">*</span>
                     </label>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <input type="email" name="email" class="long" id="email"/>
                     <span class="error" id="erroremail"></span>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <label for ="message">
                        Message <span class="required">*</span>
                     </label>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <textarea name="message" cols="50" rows="10" id="message"></textarea>
                     <span class="error" id="errormsg"></span>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>
                     <input type="submit" value="Send">      
                     <input type="reset" value="Reset"> 
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </form>
      </div>
         <p>Bonjour et bienvenue sur mon site web dévellopé from scratch, il est encore simple mais il représente mon avancée en terme de dévellopement Front End. </p>
         <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
  margin: 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  background-color: #cab4cb;
}

body {
  font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  width:auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  background-color: #f15015;
  padding: none;
  border: none;
}

header {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  height:auto;
  background-image:url(../images/6.jpg);
  background-position-y: top;
  background-position:center;
  background-size: cover;
  border:none;
  width:auto;
  margin:0px 0px;
  position:static;
}

.background {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  background-blend-mode: darken;
  height: 560px;
  width: auto;
  border: none;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  }

p {
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 2;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  color: #dadada9a;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #0f0f0f95;
  position:relative;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Josefin Slab', sans-serif;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  padding: 30px 0px;
  color: #cdcdcd9a;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #0f0f0f95;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight:normal;
}

h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight:normal;
  color: #cdcdcd9a;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

footer{
    padding:25px 0px;
    background-color:#cdcdcd9a;
    text-align:center;
}

.menu {
  display:flex;
  background-color: #dddd;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 2;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  float: right;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  display: block;
  color: rgb(120, 120, 120);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 1s ;
}

.menu a.actif {
  background-color: rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.428);
  color: #dddd;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.menu a:hover,
.menu a:hover.actif{
  background-color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
}

.form-style {
  margin:10px auto;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px 12px 10px 20px;
  font: 14px "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
.form-style td {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.form-style label{
  margin:0 0 3px 0;
  padding:0px;
  display:block;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.form-style .required{
  color:rgb(255, 0, 128);
}
.form-style input[type=submit], .form-style input[type=reset]{
  background: #cdcdcd9a;
  padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.form-style input[type=submit]:hover, .form-style input[type=reset]:hover{
  background: #cdcdcd9a;
  -moz-box-shadow:none;
  -webkit-box-shadow:none;
  box-shadow:none;
}
.form-style .field-textarea{
  height: 100px;
}
.form-style input[type=text], 
.form-style input[type=email],
textarea{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border:1px solid #BEBEBE;
  padding: 7px;
  margin:0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  outline: none;  
}
.form-style .long{
  width: 100%;
}
.form-style input[type=text]:focus, 
.form-style input[type=email]:focus,
.form-style textarea:focus{
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #cdcdcd9a;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #cdcdcd9a;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #cdcdcd9a;
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd9a;
}
.error{
  color: #D8000C;
  background-color: #FFBABA;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left:200px;
  margin-right:200px;
  margin-top:100px;
  margin-bottom :100px;
  background-color: rgb(110, 76, 110); 
  justify-content:center;
}

.flexbox-left {
  flex: 100%;
  padding: 25px 0;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  text-align: center;
  border:2px solid rgb(85, 21, 73);
  background-color: rgb(254, 199, 255);
}

.flexbox-right {
  flex: 100%;
  padding: 25px 0;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  text-align: center;
  border:2px solid rgb(85, 21, 73);
  background-color: rgb(254, 199, 255);
}

.a-propos {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.competences {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.contact {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: If your changes don't show up the CSS file could be cached. As a quick and simple solution I just add a question mark and random number after the .css in the URL.  Like **styles/portfolio.css?1235** Adding a random number will break the browser's cache.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> in your browser 
 in order to reload your assets file (seems like your browser is caching)